# AngularJS - ngSwitch with multi dimension array

Tags: angularjs, ng-switch

I'm trying to change the display result according to a given array structure. I thought that I could do so with ng-switch, but can't find the way to solve it.

I have this json:

```
0: {size: 1, room: 1, id: 1, name: "",…}
huesped: {id: 1, name: "Pablo", lastname: "Bertran", passport: "33025915N", birth: "1987-04-14", country: 10,…}
id: 1
name: ""
room: 1
size: 1
stay: {id: 1, booking: 0, room: 1, bed: 1, guest: 1, indate: "2015-11-02", outdate: "2015-12-02", hotel: 1,…}
1: {size: 1, room: 1, id: 2, name: ""}
2: {size: 1, room: 1, id: 3, name: ""}
3: {size: 1, room: 1, id: 4, name: ""}
4: {size: 1, room: 1, id: 5, name: ""}
5: {size: 1, room: 1, id: 6, name: ""}
6: {size: 2, room: 2, id: 7, name: "1"}
```

The thing is. If 'huesped' position is declared, i need A scenario.
If stay.booking > 0, scenario B.
If no stay declared, scenario C.

I tried this code:
(Assuming that the json is in $scope.beds)

```
                    <div ng-switch on="bed">
                        <div ng-switch-when="bed.huesped">
                            <div class="md-list-item-text" ng-click="accion(bed.guest.id, 2)" style="background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.7);">
                                <h3>Cama - {{::bed.id}}</h3>
                                <h4>{{ bed.huesped.name }} {{ bed.huesped.lastname }}</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-switch-when="bed.stay.booking">
                            <div class="md-list-item-text" ng-click="accion(bed.booking.id, 3)" style="background-color: rgba(255,0,0,0.7);">
                                <h3>Cama - {{::bed.id}}</h3>
                                <h4>{{ bed.booking.name }}</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div ng-switch-default>
                            <div class="md-list-item-text" ng-click="accion(bed.id, 1)" style="background-color: rgba(0,255,0,0.7);">
                                <h3>Cama - {{::bed.id}}</h3>
                                <h4>{{::bed.size}} Plaza(s)</h4>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I know something's wrong. Don't know if some detail in the code, or if ng-switch isn't able to do what I need.
Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch says:

> Be aware that the attribute values to match against cannot be expressions. They are interpreted as literal string values to match against. For example, ng-switch-when="someVal" will match against the string "someVal" not against the value of the expression $scope.someVal.

Your problem is easily resolved with `ng-if`.